# Lokuttara Paṭicca-samuppāda and the Spiral Path

Tags: pratityasamutpada, nidanas

The doctrine of paṭicca-samuppāda, or dependent arising, forms one of the core teachings of the Buddha. The Theravāda commentarial text Nettipakaraṇa divides the applications of this doctrine into two major categories. The first category, ‘lokiya paṭicca-samuppāda’ is very well known, representing  ‘worldly’ conditionality as a sequence of twelve nidānas. The second category, called ‘lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda’, creates a model of the process of liberation from the same lokiya paṭicca-samuppāda at the point of ‘jarā- maraṇa’, a term that is curiously replaced by ‘dukkha’, suffering. Applications of the second category are also referred to as the ‘Spiral Path’ after the coinage of Sangharakshita, the pre-eminent modern exponent of this aspect of Buddhist doctrine.

I have some queries regarding this:

The [Upanisā Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.023.than.html) that deals with lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda in detail, traces the chain of this transcendental conditionality step-by- step in a retrograde fashion from the ‘Destruction of the Cankers’ to ‘Faith’ and it is easy to understand how each such nidāna becomes the supporting condition of the next. However, I am unable to make out how ‘Suffering’ forms the supporting condition for ’Faith’ to arise. Could this be clarified?

The second query is why is lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda also called the ‘Spiral Path’ by Bikśu Sangharakshita?

Lastly, why is the nidāna of jarā- maraṇa replaced by the more general term dukkha in the concept of lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **OP:** why is the nidāna of jarā- maraṇa replaced by the more general term
> dukkha in the concept of lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda?

Suffering (stress) is a more general term while disease and death are specific forms of suffering.

This sutta uses the general form of dukkha, because that's the basis for connecting the lokiya paticcasamuppada to the lokuttara paticcasamuppada

> Birth is stress, aging is stress, death is stress; sorrow,
> lamentation, pain, distress, & despair are stress; association with
> the unbeloved is stress; separation from the loved is stress; not
> getting what is wanted is stress. In short, the five
> clinging-aggregates are stress.
> [AN 6.63](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.063.than.html)

> **OP:** However, I am unable to make out how ‘Suffering’ forms the
> supporting condition for ’Faith’ to arise. Could this be clarified?

One learns of the Dhamma and grows to have faith in it, but only because he seeks an end to suffering. That's the connection of suffering to faith.

In the paper "[The Spiral Path or Lokuttara Paṭicca-samuppāda](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/system/files/groups/files/Jayarava-Spiral%20Path.pdf)" by Jayarava Attwood, he explains:

> In  particular,  the Upanisā  Sutta begins  the sequence  with  faith
> arising  from  suffering  as  a  precondition. Suffering  is  the
> culmination of the *nidānas*, and replaces *jarā-maraṇa* in the usual
> *nidāna* sequence. This requires some exegesis, and some assumptions
> must be made about how *saddhā* arises out of *dukkha*. ...
>
> He seems to be saying that as a result of our experience of *dukkha* we
> develop faith in the possibility of liberation. However, it is
> not clear that *saddhā* does develop directly from the experience of
> *dukkha*, or Buddhism  would spontaneously  break out everywhere. In
> his 1966 and 1967 lectures, however, Sangharakshita  filled  in  the
> gaps a  little:  awareness of *dukkha* gives  rise  to  “restlessness”,
> which sets us “searching for something  higher”, and once we contact
> something higher then faith arises. Sangharakshita, in effect,
> introduces three intermediate steps: restlessness, searching, and
> contact with something higher.

> **OP:** why is lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda also called the ‘Spiral Path’ by > Bikśu Sangharakshita?

From the same paper, we see the suggestion that Sangharakshita called the lokuttara paticcasammupada the spiral path, to denote that it's a progressive path, as opposed to the lokiya paticcasammupada, which is the cyclic path, meaning repeating:

> Dr  Beni  Barua  took  up  the  theme  in  his  lecture Buddhism  as
> Personal  Religion,  published  in  the Mahabodhi  Society  Journal in
> 1944. It appears to be Barua who first used the terminology ‘cyclic’ and  ‘progressive’ of the two forms of conditionality;
> a terminology popularised by Sangharakshita in his writing.
> Barua presents a progressive sequence of steps, but attempts
> to locate this precise sequence in the Canon have not found it, and
> it seems Barua may have used poetic licence with canonical lists. ....
>
> Sangharakshita also highlights the singular nature of the Upanisā
> Sutta (SN  12.23)  in  combining  the  two  categories of
> *paṭicca-samuppāda* (p.136). It  was  Sangharakshita  who  coined the
> term  ‘Spiral  Path’ for this  sequence, to contrast it with the
> cyclic *nidānas*. <sup>40</sup>
>
> <sub><sup>40</sup> Sangharakshita has always taught the traditional
> ‘three lifetimes’ interpretation of the twelve *nidānas*, and often
> makes use of the *bhavacakka*</sub>

Comment: Thanks @ruben2020.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am unable to make out how ‘Suffering’ forms the supporting condition for ’Faith’ to arise. Could this be clarified?

People trust in paṭicca-samuppāda and the  PaṭiccaSamuppāda-Blessed One because they feel suffering and want to get out of suffering. If they never been effected by the suffering, they will laugh without any trust when they hear even only a word "paṭicca-samuppāda".

You can see the explanation in [upanissasutta's commentary](https://84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=12&A=1328&modeTY=2&h=Saddhati) too.

> Lastly, why is the nidāna of jarā- maraṇa replaced by the more general term dukkha in the concept of lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda?

I think it is because it is not supporting the context. The context is about the origin. The last origin is Jati. It is very long and make confuse, if the Buddha taught "'Rebirth is a condition for old age and death, sorrow, lamentation, pain, sadness, and distress to come to be. That is how this entire mass of suffering originates' cause Saddha".

Comment: while agree with the above answer about the  Upanisā Sutta, the second part of the answer about "aging & death" sounds like unsubstantiated personal or cult speculation

Comment: It is opinion because it is about the context. Pali can have tons of meaning. But I sill think same because Jati shouldn't be included in UpanissaSutta too if Jara Marana are self-view as what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The  Upanisā Sutta refers to suffering as the condition for faith because the Buddha has taught suffering experienced can be ended, for example, as follows from MN 38:

> He [the person discussed above], hearing the Dhamma, gains conviction (faith)
> in the Tathāgata and reflects: 'Household life is confining, a dusty
> path. Life gone forth is the open air. It isn't easy, living at home,
> to practice the holy life totally perfect, totally pure, a polished
> shell. What if I, having shaved off my hair & beard and putting on the
> ochre robe, were to go forth from the household life into
> homelessness?

Keep in mind the 1st noble truth (SN 56.11) also says birth (jati; identity) is suffering. Since you (Sushil Fotedar) are Indian, you show know the word "jati" means "identity" (rather than physical birth from a mother's womb).

As for aging & death, SN 12.66 explains they are types of suffering, as follows:

> As he explores he understands thus: ‘The many diverse kinds of
> suffering that arise in the world headed by aging-and-death: this
> suffering has acquisition as its source, acquisition as its origin; it
> is born and produced from acquisition. When there is acquisition,
> aging-and-death comes to be; when there is no acquisition,
> aging-and-death does not come to be.

Aging & death do not refer to physical aging & death but refer to self-identification with physical aging & death, which is why SN 12.2 refers to the birth, aging & death of "beings in a category of beings". SN 23.2 & SN 5.10 define "a being" as a "self-view".

If we read the Vibhanga of the Abhidhamma, birth, aging & death are defined therein as the birth, aging & death of "things" ("dhammas"). Here we see the beginnings of the corruption & destruction of the Buddha's Teachings; which continues today in the world by the heretical self-proclaimed "Theravada" or "Elders".

Comment: In SN Nidanavagga VibhanghaSutta, self-view is the 4th Clinging (Upadana Paticcasamuppada). In DN Mahavagga MahasatipatthanaSutta DukkhasaccaNiddesa, Jati-Jara-Marana are in DukkhaSaccaNiddesa, not SamudayaSacca, as ""And what is aging? Whatever aging, decrepitude, brokenness, graying, wrinkling, decline of life-force, weakening of the faculties of the various beings in this or that group of beings, that is called aging."

Comment: SN 23.2 & SN 5.10 define "a being" as a "self-view".

Comment: It is clearly that SN 23.2 & SN 5.10 define "a being"  as "thing (5 aggregates)" and define "diṭṭhigataṃ/(bhava&vibhava-)taṇhā" as   "self-view (attavada-upadana[4th clinging])". https://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=15&A=3842&h=diṭṭhigataṃ,suddhasaṅkhārapuñjo

Comment: yo  chando yo   rāgo   yā   nandi   yā   taṇhā  tatra  satto  tatra  visatto tasmā sattoti vuccati. https://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=17&A=4729&h=y%C4%81%20%20%20ta%E1%B9%87h%C4%81

Answer (score 0):

> The second query is why is lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda also called the ‘Spiral Path’ by Bikśu Sangharakshita?

Possible because once one has hear the good Dhamma, and as Dukkha is for sure (at least in ones death bed) to be perceiced, there is no way to get out of this "Dhamma-Wheel.
Maybe good to add that it's the wheel of Ariya (right view gained) in regard of samma-vimutti. Actually this wheel works also similar for miccha paths. Everybody may know it. And good also to understand that Saddhā comes for Saddha, meaning sacrifice, let off.
If a piece iron, hot gets you hurt, good householder would let go of it. Observe it.

> Lastly, why is the nidāna of jarā- maraṇa replaced by the more general term dukkha in the concept of lokuttara paṭicca-samuppāda?

Because this wheels turn isn't interrupted by another birth and ends with vimutti.It's the wheel toward the deathless, good householder.

Nevertheless, althought possible insured in this wheel, it's not smart to wait the heavy cause approach. So may good householder put effort into the task and stop avoiding Dukkha by running away from it.